# Multi-Tenancy with Clojure & Datomic

Tags: clojure, multi-tenant, datomic

What (if any) are the current options for Clojure, Datomic and multi-tenancy? Is this the sort of thing that leveraging existing Java libraries would be useful for?  Or would there be a more straight forward way of applying a roll-you-own solution in Clojure?

I'm completely new to Datomic and Clojure and would be open to any new paradigms of how they might solve this problem efficiently.  I'm interested in all tenanting options, but if more information is really needed, then at this early juncture I'm leaning towards:

- Single DB
- Multiple tenants sharing the same tables and have partitioned data through unique tenant keys

Comment: A likely additional requirement is that when writing Clojure code, it should be ensured that you either specify a tenant, or *explicitly* query everything regardless of tenant. Rails' `default_scope` comes to mind.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest thing you could do is to put a tenant key attribute on each of your entities. Then for any query you want to do, you can constrain it by tenant key:

```
[:find ?n
 :where
 [?c :account/name ?n]
 [?c :tenant/key :tenant.key/acme]]
```

Comment: Thanks - that's along the lines of what I was thinking.  I was just wondering if perhaps there are some slightly more interesting solutions out there that might be able to extend functionality a little further in some unexpected way (to me at least).